# Best way to store type data

Tags: python, cpython

I want to write a function `def singleton_of(cls): ...`, which need to store instance in somewhere.

Ways 1:

Store instance by `setattr(cls, ..., instance)`, but some builtin types is unable to `setattr`.

Way 2:

Store instance in a global weakref dict (`Dict[Type, object]`), but some types is unable to make weakref.

Way 3:

Store instance in a global dict (`Dict[Type, object]`), but some types is unhashable, and unable to collect.

Way 4:

Store instance in a global list (`List[Tuple[Type, object]]`), but this has terrible query performance, and unable to collect.

Way 5:

fallback way 1 to way 4 one by one.

Way 6:

Store instance in a closure (like use a decorator on cls), but this need to create the closure before call `singleton_of`, I don't like it.

**In fact, I am writing a library that should be able to store any metadata on any types.**

Any other options?

Comment: Can you show us a specific example of what that storage might look like? Like in a `dict` for instance?

Comment: @C.Nivs like Dict[Type, object] ?

Comment: When do you expect your singletons to ever be collected, regardless of the mechanism you use, considering your singletons need to stay alive as long as `singleton_of` calls for them might be made?

Comment: And do you really need to support built-in types? Calling `singleton_of(int)` or `singleton_of(list)` doesn't seem particularly meaningful or useful (not that singletons are all that useful in general, but most singleton use cases involve classes specifically designed to be singletons).

Comment: @user2357112 some temp type is dynamic created on a context which should can collect

Comment: Also, the hashability of a type's instances has no bearing on whether the type object itself is hashable. It doesn't sound like you're dealing with crazy metaclasses, and you'd have bigger problems if you were, so using types as dict keys shouldn't be a problem.

Comment: @user2357112 not only a singleton instance, it can be any type data. for example, there is my lib: https://github.com/Cologler/attributes-python and I want to add metadata on any type.